# Running mariadb on alpine container

Tags: debian, docker, mariadb, alpine-linux

I'm attempting to run mariadb on an alpine:latest (asof 20231027; 20230901; 3.18.4) container. Forgive a n00b, but I've always run it on a host system that comes with it pre-installed.

I ran mysql_install_db

```
/var/log # mariadbd --user=root
2023-10-28  3:08:23 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 10.11.5-MariaDB source revision 7875294b6b74b53dd3aaa723e6cc103d2bb47b2c as process 58
2023-10-28  3:08:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: The first data file './ibdata1' did not exist. A new tablespace will be created!
2023-10-28  3:08:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.13
2023-10-28  3:08:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of transaction pools: 1
2023-10-28  3:08:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using crc32 + pclmulqdq instructions
2023-10-28  3:08:23 0 [Note] mariadbd: O_TMPFILE is not supported on /var/tmp (disabling future attempts)
2023-10-28  3:08:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2023-10-28  3:08:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128.000MiB, chunk size = 2.000MiB
2023-10-28  3:08:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2023-10-28  3:08:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibdata1' size to 12.000MiB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2023-10-28  3:08:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibdata1' size is now 12.000MiB.
2023-10-28  3:08:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffered log writes (block size=512 bytes)
2023-10-28  3:08:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer not found: creating new
2023-10-28  3:08:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segments are active.
2023-10-28  3:08:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12.000MiB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2023-10-28  3:08:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12.000MiB.
2023-10-28  3:08:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: log sequence number 0; transaction id 3
2023-10-28  3:08:23 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2023-10-28  3:08:23 0 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table: "Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist". Some plugins may be not loaded
2023-10-28  3:08:23 0 [ERROR] Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.servers' doesn't exist
2023-10-28  3:08:23 0 [ERROR] Can't start server : Bind on unix socket: No such file or directory
2023-10-28  3:08:23 0 [ERROR] Do you already have another server running on socket: /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock ?
2023-10-28  3:08:23 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

What do I have to do to get this up and running?

Comment: So what is the question ?  Have you checked what the error is telling you to?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @RohitGupta Edited

Comment: Note [FAQ on why Docker Official Images](https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-docker#why-dont-you-provide-an-alpine-based-image) as to why MariaDB isn't alpine based. However, if you do insist, see what the docker-entrypoint.sh does, adjust a few paths for Alpine and do a similar model for the Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're possibly missing the `/run/mysqld` directory in your container.

In your container, try:

```
# sudo mkdir /run/mysqld
```

If that doesn't help: you'll need to isolate why MariaDB can't find what it's looking for. See the notes [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/troubleshooting-connection-issues/)

Comment: PROGRESSS! Still doesn't work, but that solved the error about not being able to find /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock !

Comment: Update your question with the actual log you see now.

Comment: The rest of the issue was that mariadbd looks for the files in /var/lib/mysql; i.e. you need to run mysql_install_db with the --ldata="/var/lib/mysql"